Was Gödel actually convinced that his ontological proof was correct?
The proof is obviously logically valid, but it is as obvious that it isn't logically sound.
For instance, the second axiom states that ¬P(φ) ⟺ P(¬φ), take φ(x) ⟺ x is a male human being. Then either being a male human being is a negative property or being anything else is. The axioms aren't consistent with the concept they're meant to express.
So my question is, how could a mind like Gödel's think this argument was logically sound?

Gödel does not include every possible 'property' in his argument, he was thinking of what Leibniz and others called "perfections", and SEP calls "theologically interesting" properties. Which properties are such is murky, but Gödel only needs some set of them that satisfies his axioms. Being male is hardly "theologically interesting", so it would be out. His axioms still raise a lot of issues, discussed by SEP and Gustaffson, for example, but they are not so obviously unsound.

Gödel's mind also was convinced that he was being poisoned by those around him, and he starved himself to death. It's wrong to hope that a skilled logician is always correct or always insightful. I suppose I'd ask whether his opinion matters; in logic, we care about the proof itself and not those who study it.

His opinions about the thing he created don't matter? Um, I guess. In some very literal way, they don't. Probably best not to have opinions, stick with what you know for sure.
